# How to add Carousel in 3 column Grid view

Tags: html

Actucally i am newbie to Web Designing this is my first attempt to creating website my idea for home page is that creating a 3 columns .In first column adding some text with heading,In second column adding image slideshow using carousel & in third column adding latest event with scroll event please help me for solving this problem .Thanking In Advance

Answer (score 0):

Question is little bad.

Anyway if you want to create some heading or paragraph and carousel, I think you have to using framework "Bootstrap".

Here [Bootstrap official page](https://getbootstrap.com)

Also if you want to implement scroll event, I recommend to learn Javascript and jQuery.

Here [The Modern JavaScript Tutorial](https://javascript.info), [Jquery official page](https://jquery.com)

It will be easier than you think. Try hard.